# Using @ng-select/ng-select 9.0.2. and Angular 14. AddTag not working properly. Add tag in angular form send value as null

Tags: angular14, angular-ngselect

Add tag in angular form send value as null

`<ng-select [items]="[]" [addTag]="true" [multiple]="true" bindLabel="name" bindValue="value" [(ngModel)]="applicable-to-status-codes" [closeOnSelect]="false" formControlName="applicable-to-status-codes"></ng-select>`

{{formGroup.value | json }}

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-select [items]="[]" [addTag]="true" [multiple]="true" bindLabel="name" bindValue="value" [(ngModel)]="applicable-to-status-codes" [closeOnSelect]="false" formControlName="applicable-to-status-codes"></ng-select>
```

You forget to add closing double quotation on **bindValue="value"** make sure, you are following the syntax accordingly.

Comment: I missed a double quotation when raising the question.